# the use of the underscore : q.choice_set.all()

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working on the Django

> Writing your first Django app, part 2

In the section "2.4.4 Playing with the API".
If someone could explain to me how does the underscore works in this code `q.choice_set.all()`

Comment: follow the link regarding database API that is in same tutorial prior to this, there you would see this section https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#related-objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty simple. Let's consider these two models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
        name = models.Charfield(max_lenght=100)

class Book(models.Model):
        author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        name = models.Charfield(max_lenght=100)
```

### Explain:

We have some Authors that each author has some books.
but what if we want to get all books of a specific author?
let's assume we want all books that written by `Sara`:

```
my_author = Author.objects.get(name='Sara')
```

Here is the magic! Django will automatically generate the backward relation for this object called `book_set` which contains all books writen by Sara.
The naming rule is straightforward, `<related_model_name>_set`.
So, you can get those books by writing this line:

```
sara_books = my_author.book_set.all()
```

It's nice, isn't it ? wait, it could be nicer!
`book_set` is not a good name for me, i want a more human readable name!
you can easily change this by adding `related_name` to the `author` field of `Book` model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
        author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='her_books') # you can name it anything you want
        name = models.Charfield(max_lenght=100)
```

then, you can get same books like this:

```
sara_books = my_author.her_books.all()
```

it's now more human readable :) Hope you get it.

Comment: thank you so much, I get it now thank youuuuu

Comment: I like it especially when you changed the book_set by a related name, it is magical, thank you